# Hello How to add comma in echo term to get output job city?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

Please help me PHP Masters,

I need to show cities values along with comma, 
e.g Arizona, California, Los Angeles

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $job_id, 'job_region' );
if($terms):
    foreach($terms as $term){
        echo $term->name;
endif;
```

Comment: That's not going to work because of syntax errors... And if you awnt a comma, then echo it: `echo ','`

Comment: @MarcB looks like you might have edited out the closing bracket for the for loop by mistake.

Comment: @Henders: nope. there's no `}` in the original text.

Comment: @MarcB How strange, the for loop appears to have two brackets on my edit history: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O1gxEdF6SzVFdTM1lQZ29yMVE/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O1gxEdF6SzVFdTM1lQZ29yMVE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7.0 or later, I would recommend [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($terms, 'name'));
```

Comment: TIL about array_column. Thank you.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions as of 7.0.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions according to the linked page, it does.

Comment: @Brandon Horsley OK, thougt not, thats cool i thing, Than add my non php 7 version  and  your  answer would be  perfect. :)

Comment: Sorry Brandon.. it showing   syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @WordpressWebDesignerPrince looks like I had an extra parenthesis, I have removed it, try again.

Comment: Brandon.. I added, but now it showing nothing in city field.

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way:

```
print implode(", ",array_map(function($a){return $a->name;},$terms));
```

Comment: Yes its good answer. but it showing four time in array like e.g Arizona, California, Los Angeles
Arizona, California, Los Angeles
Arizona, California, Los Angeles
Arizona, California, Los Angeles

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone for you help and support. Finally I found an answer:

```
echo '>>>>'.count($terms);
foreach($terms as $term){

     echo $term->name.', ';
```